# Problem With Zipping An AppData Folder In VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, compression, appdata

Code : ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory((Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\Folder"))

"Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'CreateFromDirectory' accepts this number of arguments."

Any Idea Why?

Comment: Probably you should try to search for the docs on the microsoft site before posting here. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.createfromdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I don't see how to add an specialfolder to the directory

Comment: You are missing the name of the zip file to create

Comment: *"Any Idea Why?"*. Because, as the error message says, no overload of `CreateFromDirectory` accepts the number of arguments you are providing. How many arguments are you providing? When you paid attention to what Intellisense told you about that method or read the documentation for that method, how many parameters did it say the method has? There's your answer. If you want to be able to write software then you should know how to use software. Help menus and context-sensitive help via the F1 key have been a thing in Windows for decades. You should use them in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution, which creates an archive called "tmp.zip" in the current directory, if the source folder exists.

Your example isn't compiling because you have to supply the path of the destination archive as well as the source folder to archive.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim destArchive = "tmp.zip"
        Dim sourceFolder As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "folder")

        If Directory.Exists(sourceFolder) Then
            If File.Exists(destArchive) Then
                File.Delete(destArchive)
            End If

            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sourceFolder, destArchive)
        End If

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```